# Asynchronous retrieving of access token using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter4j

For now I see that both function of retrieving tokens are
synchonous(getRequestToken and getAcessToken).

Is it possible to retrieve them asynchronously, and show progress on
background for example?

P.S. I work under Android platform.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just call these methods in AsyncTask and show ProgressDialog. See an [example](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Function getAcessToken() return fail if I run it on worker thread. on UI thread all OK!

Comment: Then you have answered on your question: it is not possible.

Comment: yep) But I have asked to find is there guru of Android and Twitter4j internals, to explain why it happens...

Comment: You can browse the sources(http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) by yourself. This would be the good practise.

Comment: I have investigatred and there appeared new interesting details, this error occured ONLY if I run ProgressDialog in front of start AsyncTask which get Tokens form twitter. When I replaced ProgressDialog with simple AlertDialog(without progress wheel), all works perfect: async task works and notification dialog shows on screen!